# HTTP scraper efficiency with multiprocessing

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, regex, https

I built this scraper for work that will take a csv list of firewalls from our network management system and scan a given list of HTTPS ports to see if the firewalls are accepting web requests on the management ports. I originally built this in powershell, but decided to rebuild it in python for the learning experience.

I was able to cut down the scan time substantially using multiprocessing, but I'm wondering if I can further optimize my code to get it faster.

Also, I'm very new to python. So if you have any input on better more efficient ways that I could have used to accomplish these steps would be much appreciated.

````
import urllib.request
import re
import os
import ssl
import multiprocessing

#imports a csv list of firewalls with both private and public IP addresses
f = open(r'\h.csv',"r")
if f.mode =="r":
    cont = f.read()

#regex to remove private ip addresses and then put the remaining public ip addresses in a list
c = re.sub(r"(172)\.(1[6-9]|2[0-9]|3[0-1])(\.(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}|(192)\.(168)(\.(2[0-4][0-9]|25[0-5]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){2}|(10)(\.(2[0-4][0-4]|25[0-5]|[1][0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|[0-9])){3}","",cont)
d = re.findall(r"[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}",c)

#uses HTTP requests to check if any of the 8 management ports on the addresses in the list are accepting web requests
def httpScan(list):
    iplen = len(list) 
    ports = [443, 4433, 444, 433, 4343, 4444, 4443, 4434]
    portlen = len(ports)
    for k in range(iplen):
        for i in range(portlen):
            context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
            try:
                fp = urllib.request.urlopen("https://" + str(list[k]) + ":" + str(ports[i]), context=context)
                mybytes = fp.read()
                mystr = mybytes.decode("utf8")
                fp.close()
            except:
                continue
            if "SSLVPN" in mystr:
                print(list[k] + " SSLVPN" + ": " + str(ports[i]) + "  " + str(k) + "  " + str(os.getpid()))
            elif "auth1.html" in mystr:
                print(list[k] + " MGMT" + ": " + str(ports[i]) + "  " + str(k))

#splits the list of IP addresses up based on how many CPU there are and adds each segment to a dictionary
cpu = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
sliced = int(len(d)/cpu)
mod = int(len(d))%int(cpu)
num = 1
lists = dict()
for i in range(cpu):
    if i != (cpu - 1):
        lists[i] = d[(num*sliced) - sliced:num*sliced]
        num += 1
    else:
        lists[i] = d[(num*sliced) - sliced:(num*sliced) + mod]

#starts a process for each unique segment created
t = dict()
if __name__ == "__main__": 
    for i in range(cpu):
        t[i] = multiprocessing.Process(target=httpScan, args=(lists[i],))
        t[i].start()

```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Reading File

Here is a tip, while reading, the `r` is optional

```py
f = open(r'\h.csv',"r")
```

can be written as

```py
f = open(r'\h.csv')
```

Your whole reading block can use context managers (blocks using the with keyword).

```py
with open(r'\h.csv', encoding='utf8') as f:
    cont = f.read()
```

If you are dealing with a huge text file, you might do:

```py
with open(r'\h.csv', encoding='utf8') as f:
    for ip in f:
        ip = ip.rstrip('\n')
        .. verify
```

### String

Using string formatting i.e. `.format()` can give a better idea of what's going on. It also eliminates the use of `str()` each time.
We can change this

```py
print(list[k] + " MGMT" + ": " + str(ports[i]) + "  " + str(k))
```

to that

```py
print("{} MGMT: {}  {}".format(list[k], ports[i], k))
```

and as from 3.6+, adding an f

```py
print(f"{list[k]} MGMT: {ports[i]}  {k}")
```

### Loop Iteration

In many other languages, you need the index while looping to have the element at this index. Python provides a nice and intuitive way to loop over elements

The current implementation:

```py
ports = [443, 4433, 444, 433, 4343, 4444, 4443, 4434]
portlen = len(ports)
for i in range(portlen):
    print(ports[i])
```

But the pythonic way is:

```py
ports = [443, 4433, 444, 433, 4343, 4444, 4443, 4434]
for port in ports:
    print(port)
```

`port` here gives you the element directly.
If ever you still want the index, you do:

```py
for i, port in enumerate(ports):
```

where `i` is the index.

### Miscellaneous

Here:

```py
cpu = int(multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

No need to cast to int as `multiprocessing.cpu_count()` already returns an integer. You can verify for int by `type(multiprocessing.cpu_count())`

Normally with `.start()`, you must include a `.join()`, as this allows all child processes to terminate before exiting.

```py
for ...:
   ... .start()

for ...:
   ... .join()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: You are welcomed!